# Ampliar gráfica ggplot eje x

Tags: r

Estoy realizando un ggplot a partir de una base de datos como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cual he realizado el siguiente código para obtener el gráfico de interés:

```
 ggplot(Tabla2, aes(Tiempo, Value, group = Bacteria, color = Bacteria)) +    
   geom_point(size=5) +
   geom_line(size=3)+
   my_theme()+
   scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0.1),limits=c(0,0.6),labels = scales::percent)+
   labs( x = "", y="Percentage (%)",face = "bold")+
   geom_vline(xintercept = 2.5, colour="red", linetype = "longdash",size=2.5) + 
   guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)))+
   geom_text_repel(
     aes(label = paste0((Value*100),"%")), data = Resultados_Rosa_formated_end,
     fontface ="plain", color = "black", size = 8,
     nudge_x = 0.1, direction = "y", hjust = "left",
     segment.linetype = 1.2,
     segment.curvature = -1e-20,
     segment.size      = 0.8
   )+geom_text_repel(
     aes(label = paste0((Value*100),"%")), data = Resultados_Rosa_formated_begin,
     fontface ="plain", color = "black", size = 8,nudge_x = -0.2,direction = "y", hjust = "right",
     segment.linetype = 1.2,
     segment.curvature = -1e-20,
     segment.size      = 0.8
   )
```

Obteniendo la siguiente gráfica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podeis ver el espacio a la derecha del eje x es muy ajustado y no me permite ver los valores de geom_text_repel.
¿Cómo podría agrandar la gráfica por el lado derecho del eje x?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: ¿Qué significa "agrandar"? Viendo el ejemplo te sugiero dos temas a investigar 1) Con `geom_repel` puedes hacer que las etiquetas no aparezcan alineadas verticalmente, es decir unas a la derecha del punto y otras a la izquierda, eso mejoraría mucho la legibilidad 2) La otra posibilidad es que tienes 6 puntos con lo que parece el mismo valor (1.4), deja una sola observación con esta etiqueta y el resto con NA.